# How to change weights on multiples vertices (or render multiple vertices active simultanously)?

Tags: rigging

Does anyone knows how to change the weights of multiple vertices in Blender .. WITH the N menu ( right side ) .. it's SOOO useful ( as in 3dsmax ).. here you can only see 1 vertex at the time ( I know you can go the Vertex group par of the mesh but it's not LIVE.. and really less useful and intuitive )
https://youtu.be/K75O1dbeJU0

Answer (score 1):

you can select multiple vertices, N -> side panel -> enter vertex weight -> paste to selected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How do you set multiple weights from the sidebar simultaneously?  You cannot.  You can either set a weight or copy weights from active selection, not both at the same time.

How do you set values for multiple vertices simultaneously, in a way that provides continuous feedback?  It depends on exactly what way you want to modify the values, but one way is via a "levels" operation in weight paint mode:

[image]

Here, I am multiplying the value of the active group of all selected vertices by 0.610.  I can treat the gain  as a slider and get continuous visual feedback on my choices (although it may be a bit choppy.)

If what I wanted was a brute assignment, I might begin by setting those vertices to 0 and then using the "offset" section of the levels operation instead, which adds weight to the selected vertices.